# How to mass folder named according to some expression

Tags: windows, scripting, directory, utilities

I want to create many folders whose names are like `folder_x` where x is an even number less than 256. Is there a unix command/dos command or some shellscript that I can run to do this?
Or may be some free utility program that does mass folder creation?

I want to do this on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash and other compatible shells:

```
for i in $(seq 0 2 255) ; do mkdir "folder_$i" ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple bash script will do that.

```
for i in {0..256..2}
  do
    mkdir folder_$i
  done
```

Answer (score 2):

In a Windows `cmd` prompt, this would be:

```
for /L %i in (0,2,255) do mkdir folder_%i
```

If you want to add this to a .bat file, remember it will need double `%`:

```
for /L %%i in (0,2,255) do mkdir folder_%%i
```